# how i can set textview over imageview and set text center at bottom of image boundry inside horizontal Recycler View

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, textview, imageview

I have created recyclerView. I have created custom layout and it contain image and textview.

I added imageview and set it's hight and width to wrap_content and programmatically set it'z size 360 x 360.

I want to overlay textview bottom and center. but problem is if text is big it was goes out of bound it was utilize the screen cell untill end of the screen width.

I want it text will center and bottom and it wil reside into image view boundry and if text size big it will adjust inside imageview.

Here is What i want 
[image]

What i get 
[image]

here is my xml code i have paste here plz help how i can fix this design issue

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageViewSmallBanner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/image_1" />


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearBannerOffer"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/drawable_linear_corner_radius">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewOffer"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#efefef"
                android:paddingStart="4dp"
                android:paddingEnd="4dp"
                android:text="30% off"
                android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_light"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="10sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewHighlightTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="blah blaj blah blah blah blah blah blah "
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create your layout in Constraint Layout like this:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewSmallBanner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewOffer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:background="#efefef"
        android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_light"
        android:paddingStart="4dp"
        android:paddingEnd="4dp"
        android:text="30% off"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageViewSmallBanner"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageViewSmallBanner"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageViewSmallBanner"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewHighlightTitle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:text="blah blaj blah blah blah blah blah blah "
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageViewSmallBanner"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageViewSmallBanner"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: nop this is not working .. there are to list item need to show . when i am using your layout it show shame view just text is centrlized... still text goes out of bound

Comment: what is your view I don't know?

Comment: your view is shows like question view. it show remaining nothing more change just text is centrlized

Comment: look at both pictures in the question and what he want ?

Comment: naah... not working as i required. still text over image boundry issue

Comment: what boundry issue

Comment: do you need curved boundry ?

Answer (score 0):

[[image: Check screenshot]

check my code if it is helpful for you :)

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/demo"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="OFFER"
                android:paddingStart="15dp"
                android:paddingEnd="15dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:background="@drawable/back"
                android:layout_margin="10dp" />


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:text="Up to 50% off on Singer"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="40sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

        </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: if you are creating the view in Relative layout the why you set the parent view is LinerLayout. Here what is the use of Liner Layout?

Answer (score 0):

Hi try Following code to archive this 
 1. use CardView for rounded corner 
 2. Constraint layout for dynamic spacing of your views.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/image_card"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardElevation="2dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/lightt_gray"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <!-- youtube thumbnail view to show the thumbnail of videos -->
            <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageViewSmallBanner"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:minHeight="100dp"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/thumbnail_image_view_desc"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:src="@drawable/app_icon"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>
        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/video_header1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/app_name"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:padding="0dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
          />

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/video_header2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/app_name"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:maxLines="2"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:padding="0dp"
                android:layout_margin="20dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try- this change for the textview hight light Title:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewHighlightTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="blah blaj blah blah blah blah blah blah "
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
```